# How to import photo and add it to array in react?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, image

I am a trainee in react.js so please help me.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import './imgSlider.css'
import image1 from './a.png'
import image2 from './b.png'
import image3 from './c.png'


function ImgSlider() {

    const [ImgSlide, setImgSlide] = useState([
        {
          photo: {image1}
        },
        {
          photo: {image2}
        },
        {
          photo: {image3}
        }
    ]);
    const [Index, setIndex] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div>
    {ImgSlide.map((val, i) => {
        return <div className="imgSlideDiv">{val.name}</div>;
    })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImgSlider
```

I tried many methods but this was the nearest I got to. If there is any other method, suggest me.

Comment: That's a good question! I am following this question to see if there is any correct answer for it.

Comment: Are you importing it all from your local itself?

Answer (score 0):

first thing you don't need the curly braces when setting the image to the state

```
photo: {image1} // not like this 
photo: image1 // instead like this
```

and the images should be in an `img tag` and set the `src prop` of the img element to the imported image like this `<img src={image1} />`

Your component should be like this  :

```
import  React from "react";
import {useState} from "react" ; 
import image1 from './test1.jpg'
import image2 from './test2.jpg'
import image3 from './test3.jpg'
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [ImgSlide, setImgSlide] = useState([
    {
      photo: image1
    },
    {
      photo: image2
    },
    {
      photo: image3
    }
]);
  return (
    <div>
      {ImgSlide.map((val, i) => {
         return <div className="imgSlideDiv"><img src={val.photo} /></div>
        })}
    </div>
    
  );
}
```